# Azure Storage Block Blob upload from client side Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

Azure Storage has a guide with the following code

```
        blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('mycontainer', 'myblob','test.txt', function(error, result, response){
      if(!error){
        // file uploaded
      }
    });
```

When I use this snippet of code in my project I get an error returned with message: "ENOENT, no such file or directory '/main_900.jpg'"

My code looks like this

```
 var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService('<myStorageName>', '<myStorageKey>',
            'https://<myStorageName>.blob.core.windows.net/');

    blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('mycontrainer', 'blob', myScope.currentFile.name, function (error, result, response) {
                if (!error) {
                    var hey = "file was a success";// file uploaded
                } else {
                var oops = "error";
            }

        });
```

where myScope.currentFile.name is the name of the file I am trying to upload (main_900.jpg).  I know my blobSvc is correct and connected to my Azure storage because I was able to create a container with code:

```
blobSvc.createContainerIfNotExists('mycontainer', function (error, result, response) {

        });
```

What are the three parameters suppose to be? I believe mine are entered correctly. Where does the local file have to be? I've tried it in a number of directories and tried changing the file name to direct there.  None of it seems to work.  Could anyone direct me on what I am doing wrong?

Here is a link to the Microsoft guide: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/#upload-a-blob-into-a-container

Comment: I guess you need to specify the full file path?

Comment: You realize your storage key is visible for anyone able to view the JavaScript? I'm assuming this is run in the browser and not on nodejs. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the source code at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L2890 for the details.

The first three params are:

```
* @param {string}   container        The container name.
* @param {string}   blob             The blob name.
* @param {string}   localFileName    The local path to the file to be uploaded.

BlobService.prototype.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile = function (container, blob, localFileName, optionsOrCallback, callback){
...
}
```

So regarding your issue, it should be the path issue. Please double check the file path, you may use the `fs` module to check the file path first:

```
var fs = require('fs');

if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.